# How to preform a regression on yearly mean?

Tags: excel, statistics

If i have a set of data,how can i find the yearly mean in excel and how to perform a regression on the yearly mean in excel?
For example:

```
Date  loss
2015     5
2016     3
2016     6
2014     7
2015     4
2015     5
2014     2
2014     1
```

Comment: What would you expect your regression of the yearly mean to be? and how is it different from the mean?

Comment: I want to find the inflation factor by using regression on the yearly mean

Comment: I should find the yearly mean first, and then perform a regression on it.

Comment: giving the results you expect from your posted data would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a scatter plot and then take the line of best fit  as one form of regression.

Select a point on the data series and right click.  From the menu that comes up select add trend line.  Over ont he right (depending on your veriosn of excel) you should have the option to display equation on chart.

[image: graph with trend line showing equation of trend line]

[image]